# How do I make my buttons show up in random places until the button is pressed?

Tags: java, android

I have tried basically everything! I am trying to make a short mini-game where you have to press the image that pops up on the screen. The image moves to different points of the application randomly, but the problem is I cannot continue moving the image around! The image is a button by the way!

**GameView.java**

```
package interactive.siddiqui.fortuneteller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Random;


public class GameView extends Activity{

private Button btn;


private boolean tf = false;

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 500;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_view);

    boolean foo = true;
    while(foo = true) Click();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game_view, menu);
    return true;
}

public void Click() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
            Random r = new Random();

            int x = r.nextInt(480);
            int y = r.nextInt(800);

            btn.setX(x);
            btn.setY(y);




        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




public void bob(View view){
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GameView.this, Finished.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            tf = true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

This mainly applies to Java, but I will add in the corresponding XML file too.

**XML File**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"      
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="interactive.siddiqui.fortuneteller.GameView"
 android:background="@drawable/background_fortune">

 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text=""
     android:id="@+id/button9"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:background="@drawable/small_fortune"
     android:onClick="bob"
     android:layout_x = "0dp"
     android:layout_y = "0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I do this? I just want the button to show up in random places until the button is clicked! THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK, by the way...

Comment: You want to have your button stationary when button is clicked. But you are trying to move it when button is clicked.

Comment: Take the bullet and learn OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a infinite while, which locks the UI thread (so you won't see any updates to the position), use a Timer and a TimerTask.

Also, your `bob` method, you were assigning a new click listener, which I assume t wasn't what you actually wanted.

Anyway, try this and if you have any doubt about the code, just ask :)

```
package interactive.siddiqui.fortuneteller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class GameView extends Activity{

    private Button btn;


    private boolean tf = false;
    private boolean canMove = true;
    private Timer timer;

    private final long SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 500;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_view);

        start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        canMove = true;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        moveButton();
                    }
                },
                SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH,
                SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH
        );
    }

    private void moveButton()
    {
        if(!canMove){ return; }

        runOnUiThread(
                 new Runnable()
                 {
                     @Override
                     public void run()
                     {
                        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
                        Random r = new Random();

                        int x = r.nextInt(480);
                        int y = r.nextInt(800);

                        btn.setX(x);
                        btn.setY(y);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




    public void bob(View view)
    {
        canMove = false;

        if(timer != null)
        {
            try
            {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

            timer = null;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(GameView.this, Finished.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        tf = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!

Comment: Timer is the way to go, otherwise you could also look into the Handler method which you can use to delay-execute a command. But since it has to keep moving, I guess the timer is better. If you want to change the speed of the jumps, with the timer you have to change the timer or count ticks. With the handler you could set the next time differently, allthough go with timer.